# switched values in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary that contains a long list of keys. The problem is that after executing these lines of code, the values changed their position inside a list.

The code:

```
def remove_repeating_value(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            remove_repeating_value(value)
            for k, v in value.items():
                if v is None:
                    del value[k]
        else:
            dictionary[key] = list(set(value))
            if None in dictionary[key]:
                dictionary[key].remove(None)

    return dictionary


# calling function
print(remove_repeating_value(data))
```

Here is a sample of dictionary before executing the code above:

```
{'C4QY10_e': {'protein accession': ['C4QY10_e',
   'C4QY10_e',
   'C4QY10_e',
   'C4QY10_e',
   'C4QY10_e'],
  'sequence length': ['1879', '1879', '1879', '1879', '1879'],
  'analysis': ['Pfam', 'Pfam', 'Pfam', 'Pfam', 'Pfam'],
  'signature accession': ['PF18314',
   'PF02801',
   'PF18325',
   'PF00109',
   'PF01648'],
  'signature description': ['Fatty acid synthase type I helical domain',
   'Beta-ketoacyl synthase',
   'Fatty acid synthase subunit alpha Acyl carrier domain',
   'Beta-ketoacyl synthase',
   "4'-phosphopantetheinyl transferase superfamily"],
  'start location': ['328', None, '139', None, '1761'],
  'stop location': ['528', None, '300', None, '1861'],
  'e-value': ['4.7E-73', None, '1.3E-72', None, '1.4E-18'],
  'interpro accession': ['IPR041550', None, 'IPR040899', None, 'IPR008278'],
  'interpro description': ['Fatty acid synthase type I',
   None,
   'Fatty acid synthase subunit alpha',
   None,
   "4'-phosphopantetheinyl transferase domain"],
  'nunique': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  'domain_count': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}
```

And here is a sample after executing the code:

```
{C4QY10_e': {'protein accession': ['C4QY10_e'],'sequence length': ['1879'], 'analysis': ['Pfam'], 'signature accession': ['PF00109', 'PF01648', 'PF18325', 'PF18314', 'PF02801'], 'signature description': ['Fatty acid synthase type I helical domain', 'Beta-ketoacyl synthase', "4'-phosphopantetheinyl transferase superfamily", 'Fatty acid synthase subunit alpha Acyl carrier domain'], 'start location': ['1761', '328', '139'], 'stop location': ['528', '1861', '300'], 'e-value': ['1.3E-72', '1.4E-18', '4.7E-73'], 'interpro accession': ['IPR008278', 'IPR040899', 'IPR041550'], 'interpro description': ['Fatty acid synthase type I', "4'-phosphopantetheinyl transferase domain", 'Fatty acid synthase subunit alpha'], 'nunique': [1], 'domain_count': [5]}
```

The change is contained in lists, for example:

'start location': ['328', None, '139', None, '1761']

into:

'start location': ['1761', '328', '139']

As you can see the string '1761' moved to [0] position. And the problem also occurs in other lists, not only for 'start location' key.

Comment: So basically, your question is asking how to remove duplicates in a `list` while preserving order?

Comment: I guess it is...

Comment: Try changing `dictionary[key] = list(set(value))` to `dictionary[key] = list(dict.fromkeys(value))`. A `set` has arbitrary order. After `3.7`, `dict` order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you re converting `list` into `set` the order is changed because the `set` is unordered data structure try this to keep order instead of:

```
dictionary[key] = list(set(value))
```

do:

```
dictionary[key]=list(dict.fromkeys(value).keys())
```